# How do I access function names in R?

Tags: r

I am writing a function that receives two parameters: a data frame, and a function, and, after processing the data frame, summarizes it using the function parameter (e.g. mean, sd,...). My question is, how can I get the name of the function received as a parameter?

Comment: give us example code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
f <- function(x) deparse(substitute(x))
f(mean)
# [1] "mean"
f(sd)
# [1] "sd"
```

Answer (score 2):

`do.call` may be what you want here. You can get a function name as character value, and then pass that and a `list` of arguments to `do.call` for evaluation.   For example:

```
X<-"mean"
do.call(X,args=list(c(1:5)) )
[1] 3
```

Comment: Or you also could use `match.fun` like in `match.fun(X)(1:3)`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question, but it seems like you could simply have the function name as a parameter, and evaluate the function like normal within your function. This approach works fine for me. The ellipsis is for added parameters to your function of interest.

```
myFunc=function(data,func,...){return(func(data,...))}
myFunc(runif(100), sd)
```

And if you'd want to apply it to every column or row of a `data.frame`, you could simply use an apply statement in `myFunc`.

Comment: yes, you misunderstood. The OP wants `"func"` given `func`.

Comment: @flodel are you sure? I thought the name of the function was an input parameter, not an output.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my try, perhaps, you want to return *both* the result and the function name:

```
y <- 1:10

myFunction <- function(x, param) {
  return(paste(param(x), substitute(param)))
}

myFunction(y, mean)
# [1] "5.5 mean"
```